# New column based on another multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my dataframe.

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 21 |
| 0 | 0 |

Now want to add a column name 'c' which return yes when a or b is non-zero and return no when a and b is zero

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | yes |
| 1 | 21 | yes |
| 0 | 0 | no |

Answer (score 1):

If need test all columns compare by `0` and test if all values per row by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with set `yes`, 'no' by  [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['c'] = np.where(df.eq(0).all(axis=1), 'no','yes')

print (df)
    a   b    c
0  12   0  yes
1   1  21  yes
2   0   0   no
```

Another idea is test if at leastone value is not `0` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), then is used mapping:

```
df['c'] = df.ne(0).any(axis=1).map({False: 'no',True:'yes'})
```

If possible multiple columns and need test only `a,b` columns:

```
cols = ['a','b']
df['c'] = np.where(df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1), 'no','yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
import numpy as np
df['c'] = np.where( (df['a']>0) | (df['b']>0), 'yes', 'no')
```